# How to name a coroutine version of a function?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

Say I have two functions, one that takes a sequence of values and returns a sequence (list/tuple).
Another which is a coroutine, instead of taking a sequence it accepts values via send and instead of returning a list it yield's the values.

What would be a good naming convention to differentiate the two functions?

---

Possible options:

For the function: `foo`

- `foo_iter`
- `foo_co`
- `foo_coroutine`

---

Edit: it's been pointed out that the main version of the function could be the iterable one which could be converted into a list: eg: `list(foo(seq))`. In general this is true, but in the spesific case I need to use `yield/send` in a way that means this isn't an option.
The coroutine is a bit more involved than I made out in the question, so assume both are needed.

Comment: do you need the list-version? Just call `list(foo(seq))`.

Comment: Good point, but yes - I need a list version because the coroutine version has some involved interaction in how the `send()` function is used.
It's more complex then I made out in the question - but I didn't think that was necessary to include since it's about naming.

Comment: If you don't have two functions, that do basically the same, you don't have to worry about naming.

Comment: I would go with `foo_gen`, as it is actually a generator

Comment: Since this takes args via `send()`, on #Python IRC I was told this is a coroutine, not a generator *(though I'm not sure if this is a clear distinction between the two).*